# Where can I find linked fonts in my theme?

Tags: php

I get 404 error because of absent of fonts  in my theme ( .ttf , .wof). In my opinion the only solution for this is to delete the request from my them,  but I cant find the request string. I've looked through all .php files from my editor but I couldn't find any `.ttf` or  file even.

Answer (score 1):

Your Theme about used Google webfonts i think. Better try find this link from your .css and theme php files

"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?".

if you got anything, just similar to it, just visit google.com/fonts , for better font selections. may be your font is not linked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the network tab of your browser's developer tools to see what the exact path and filename is for the files that are producing the 404 error. You could then use this to do a search in your theme files.

Self-hosted fonts would be linked in your theme's style.css file or another stylesheet... If there's a css folder have a look in that as well.

The 404 suggests that the theme probably isn't using a font hosting service unless it's somehow been misconfigured. If you can't find any links to fonts in your stylesheets have a look in your theme's `header.php` or `functions.php` file for linked styles or JavaScript from the font hosting service.